# What is the "Angular" way to handle form validation?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

So, I'm looking at this piece of code:

```
function checkFormElements(field) {
    if ($scope.options === undefined || $scope.optionsForm.$error[field] === undefined ) {
        return false;
    }
    var result = false;
    $.each($scope.optionsForm.$error[field], function(index, value) {
        // TODO: There *has* to be a better way than this to get the element. Angular must know the form control, whether it's named or not.
        var element = $('[name=' + value.$name + ']');
        if (!element.prop('disabled')) {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

$scope.formIsInvalid = function() {
    return checkFormElements("pattern");
};

$scope.fieldIsEmpty = function() {
    if ($scope.options === undefined || $scope.formIsInvalid()) {
        return false;
    }
    return checkFormElements("required");
};
```

And I'd quite like to clean up that TODO.

The form elements are generated in the directive by:

```
    template: '\
        <input class="output-input" id="{{fieldName}}-input" name="{{fieldName}}" type="text" maxlength="64" ng-model="item.name" ng-pattern="pattern" ng-required="true" ng-trim="false" ng-disabled="item.save===false">\
        <div class="save-column" ng-if="showSave"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.save" ng-disabled="item.save === undefined" ng-checked="(item.save === undefined) || item.save"></div>\
    ',
```

The basic functionality is:

- There are multiple edit fields with a save box next to them.
- If the fields have junk in them, then the form field $error.pattern exists. If the field is empty, then the $error.required exists
- We loop over all that kind of errors, check if the element generating it is enabled (because disabled boxes can hold junk content or be blank) and if they do then we declare the form invalid and thus not fit to be sent.

It feels like there's a way to solve this that's more in angular's style, and I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: You might want to check this blog out - https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/paulyoder/angular-bootstrap-show-errors) is a good article about angularjs validations with bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You need can see all the properties of the form by giving it a name.
Render Your form name to see everything AngularJS know about it.

```
<form name="myForm">

</form>

{{myForm}}
```

I think you should also require ngModel, but I'm not sure about what you're doing here.
Could you add a fiddle or a picture?

Comment: I'll try and get an example fiddle up and running at some point, but the core behaviour is that, for each field created via that directive in the latter box, we need to check whether the ng-pattern's been violated, or if the ng-required state is violated, but only if ng-disabled is false. Which is what the code above does, but in a self-confessed bassackwards way.

Answer (score -1):

That's not the way. Controllers need to do as little job as it is possible. You need to use directives for form validation. The directive describes behaviour of field and then you call it in template:

```
<form name="myName" novalidate ng-submit="action(myName)">
    <input class="output-input" id="{{fieldName}}-input" name="{{fieldName}}" ng-model="item.name" .... myDirective>
</form>
```

Also maxlength, minlength, required are the directives:

```
angular.module('myModule.directive', [])

.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                 //function checking if field is valid or not
                 scope.myName.item.name.$setValidity('myDirective', isValid);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I recommend you reading angularjs manual for directives:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The form *is* in the directive, it's only the upper code block that's in the controller.

Unless I'm missing something, your code doesn't appear to actually include the code that handles checking the regex, or checking the emptiness value, or checking the disabled value, which is what the code's above's trying to solve.

Comment: Basically, that "//function checking if field is valid or not" is the relevant bit I need help with.

Comment: scope.$watch monitors changes in your form. You shouldn't check all fields at every change. The value argument is the change in your form. In the marked place with comment you can make your: var myRegEx = /^MYREGEX$/i; if (myRegEx.test(value) == false)